# How to make Compiz start automatically?

Tags: debian, compiz, metacity

I'm using Linux Debian Squeeze and I already have compiz installed. I want metacity stop automatically boot, and instead want compiz to start automatically.

Comment: Have you seen/tried the [Debian Wiki entry on using `compiz` instead of Metacity](http://wiki.debian.org/Compiz#Start_compiz_instead_of_the_default_Gnome_Window_Manager)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change the gconf key with
>
> `gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager compiz`
>
> You can go back to the default Gnome Metacity window manager with
>
> `gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager gnome-wm`
>
> If this fails You can simply add compiz --replace
>   to your startup applications. Name the entry what you want, give it
>   whatever description you want, but make the command
>
> `compiz --replace`

Source: http://wiki.debian.org/Compiz#Start_compiz_instead_of_the_default_Gnome_Window_Manager

Comment: In case anyone else ends up with the same problem and finds this question, what does that command do?  That info would help others to understand not just what to do, but also why it works to fix the problem.

Comment: Still curious what that command is doing that makes it a useful answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @killermist what do you think about it now?

Comment: Much better.  I'll have to remember to come back and give it a +1 when I have more votes again.  I think it is always better to know why something works than to just have the steps.  Thanks for expanding it.

Comment: @killermist Thanks, do not forget the vote up